# Is it plausible to treat Klinefelter Syndrome with Anadrol?

Tags: steroids, testosterone

A known Klinefelter's treatment is testosterone, testosterone in average males has negative side effects when consuming it synthetically, due to Klinefelter's people lacking testosterone they get the benefits they lack, without taking in count hepatic damage, would a person with Klinefelter's would have some of the negative side effects Anadrol represents? for example, Gyneco is the most known side effect, but Klinefelter's already have Gyneco and they take testosterone precisely to revert it, so... would their Gyneco be worsen or treated?

Comment: Hi Mrc4t987, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.